# React 18 useEffect hook pulling data twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react so really sorry if this question has already been asked.

I am fetching data from an API in an useEffect hook and I only want to fetch it once but instead its being fetched twice for some reason.

Here's the code of useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTasks = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/tasks')
      const data = await res.json()
      console.log(data)
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        setNewTaskContent(newTaskContent => [...newTaskContent, <Task task={data[i]} />])
      }
    }
    fetchTasks()
  }, [])
```

This was supposed to run once when the page was loaded but I am getting an array of data twice.

And if I am removing the dependency array from the hook, its fetching data continuously in a loop.

Comment: Is this in dev mode using `React.StrictMode`?

Answer (score 2):

In [strict mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode), React will render every component twice during development. To prevent getting duplicate data, you should return a cleanup function from `useEffect` that ignores the current request. (Do not disable strict mode unless you have a very good reason to.)

```
useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;
    const fetchTasks = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/tasks')
      const data = await res.json();
      if (ignore) return;
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        setNewTaskContent(newTaskContent => [...newTaskContent, <Task task={data[i]}/>])
      }
    }
    fetchTasks();
    return () => ignore = true;
}, []);
```

Comment: Requiring this workaround seems like a very good reason to disable strict mode.